# How to access XML data via SImpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML source which appears to be using some d2LogicalModel markup, and I'm really struggling to figure out how to extract any data from it using PHP's SimpleXML.

I've included a cut-down version of the XML below: How do I extract the carParkIdentity? 
How to I access a specific 's id?

Then I can figure out the rest of the data myself!

Thanks a bunch!

```
<d2lm:d2LogicalModel xmlns:d2lm="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" modelBaseVersion="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0 http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0/DATEXIISchema_1_0_1_0.xsd">
  <d2lm:exchange>...</d2lm:exchange>
  <d2lm:payloadPublication lang="en" xsi:type="d2lm:SituationPublication">
    <d2lm:situation id="CPN0017">
      <d2lm:situationRecord id="CPN0017_1" xsi:type="d2lm:CarParks">
        <d2lm:situationRecordCreationTime>2017-01-03T10:47:41</d2lm:situationRecordCreationTime>
        <d2lm:situationRecordVersion>1</d2lm:situationRecordVersion>
        <d2lm:carParkIdentity>Chapelfield, Chapelfield Road, N:CPN0017</d2lm:carParkIdentity>
        <d2lm:carParkOccupancy>77.0</d2lm:carParkOccupancy>
        <d2lm:carParkStatus>enoughSpacesAvailable</d2lm:carParkStatus>
      </d2lm:situationRecord>
    </d2lm:situation>
  </d2lm:payloadPublication>
</d2lm:d2LogicalModel>
```

Comment: did you try to paste same heading in google? If no then paste and you will get lot of tutorials and answer .http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Then if all else fails [Read the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) Code something, and then come back if you get any problems

Comment: I have read through the examples and documentation for SimpleXML, but they don't seem to be working for this particular markup, which is where I'm having difficulties!

Maybe I phrased the question wrong - I don't need help with SimpleXML on a basic level, I need help using SimpleXML for this particular weird markup which I'm having minimal luck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this piece of code:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.XML');

foreach ($xml->xpath('//d2lm:carParkIdentity') as $child) {

    echo $child;

}
```

Also, you are more than welcome to take a look on XPath syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: The code I've provided returns d2lm:carParkIdentity text value, and that's what was your question about...

Comment: Oh! What is with the double slashes at the beginning? Is that to escape the ':' in the middle? I guess that is where I was going wrong, as I've been trying to access them like: $xml->payloadPublication->situation etc!

Edit: Yeah sorry for the previous comment, that was meant to go on the comment above.. This is a great solution!

Comment: @nomaki, It is XPath query that allows you to retrieve data from XML documents. I've updated my answer with link to XPath documentation.